# marriage by a civil official

Tags: meaning

What does "a civil official" mean in the following context?
How goes a marriage by a civil official?

> In a 2,500-person nationally representative survey commissioned for my book, I found that weddings with religious leaders of different faiths are rare: Only 4% of interfaith — and, surprisingly, 2% of same-faith — couples employ them. Instead, interfaith couples are much more likely to have used a civil official.

Comment: A government official a "civil wedding" is a non-religous one. A government employee is a civil servant in BE

Answer (score 1):

Following the answer from @BlessedGeek, I would add that, in the UK (and specifically England), *every* marriage has to be administered by a 'recognised' official. That would include *many* - probably most, but not all - religious ministers, etc., and civil **Registrars**.

**Registrars** (more particularly the *Registrar of Births, Marriages and Deaths*) would not normally be existing civil officials who are also authorised to administer marriages (as described by @BlessedGeek), but officials whose primary job is to maintain the official Registers of Births, Marriages and Deaths.

[This answer is based on my 'background' understanding of the UK system within England, not on any research or direct experience - except of being married in a *Registry Office* - and should be read in that light. I would expect the general principles apply to the rest of the UK, but details may differ.]

Comment: In Scotland, the Registrar General has extended the right to perform legal marriages to Humanist celebrants. http://www.humanism-scotland.org.uk/content/wedding_ceremonies/.  It´s a discretionary dispensation which he has been making on a rolling basis every year since 2005 - he (or a future Registrar General) could change his mind unless the Scottish parliament legislates to extend the capability officially to Humanists.

Comment: @itsbruce Thanks. Apologies for not thinking about differences between different parts of the UK - I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In many countries and jurisdictions, it is legislated (by law) that a marriage is legally recognised only after the marriage vows had been administered by a person licensed to administer such vows.

In many countries and jurisdictions, a religious minister could apply to be a licensed marriage officiator to legally administer marriage vows. However, many couples in such countries either are unable or prefer not to have their marriage administered by a religious minister. In such cases, their marriage could be administered by the city clerk, mayor, justice-of-peace (perhaps, the police chief even?) or any civilian government official allowed by law to administer marriages. Such marriages are said to be officiated by a civil official, and are usually termed *civil marriage* or *civil ceremony*.

There are rare jurisdictions where anyone could administer marriage vows where the marriage would be legally recognised (Montana, for instance). However, such marriages if not officiated by a civil government official or by a religious minister would be a *civil marriage* but not officiated by a *civil official* but by a *civil person*. (What if the marriage was administered by a friend who happened to be an off-duty soldier?)

Therefore, civil marriage rituals are usually differentiated from religious marriage rituals by not being administered by a religious minister.

OTOH, if a couple (of soldiers) wish to be married not by a chaplain (religious officer in the military) but by a superior officer, such marriages would not be considered a civil marriage since they are not officiated by a civil official of the government but by a marshal official of the government.

Comment: Sea captains come to mind too

Comment: Is there amy maritime law or convention constraining who a ship captain should be, eligible to legally administer a marriage? A fishing boat captain could administer? What is a group of gay couples rented a yacht and appointed a friend as captain, and had their "captain" marry them?

Comment: Actually it seems I am beleiveing a myth http://www.straightdope.com/columns/read/546/are-ships-captains-allowed-to-marry-people-at-sea